# [Java][Selenium] How do I find and send clicks to a button that has the same name as other buttons in the frontend

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently working on a test suite and upon F12 and inspecting elements, I have several buttons that do not have id, have the same name, they are under the same class and the only thing different is the link to the page that they take you to.

Is there any way I can tell my webdrive to pick my specific button based on the link/ahref of the button?

If the question seems to be newbie please excuse me, it's only been 3 weeks since I started writing test suites in Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate elements by XPath or by CSS Selector based on any combination of any attributes. Also it can contain dependency to some parent element(s).
For example if your buttons HTMLs are looking like this:

```
<button class="button" href="link1">
<button class="button" href="link2">
<button class="button" href="link3">
```

You can use the following XPaths

```
//button[@hef='link1']
//button[@hef='link2']
//button[@hef='link3']
```

Or CSS selectors

```
button[href='link1']
button[href='link2']
button[href='link3']
```

In case the `href` attribute values are very long or partially changing you still can create locators based or partially values, like the following
XPaths

```
//button[contains(@hef,'link1')]
//button[contains(@hef,'link2')]
//button[contains(@hef,'link3')]
```

Or CSS selectors

```
button[href*='link1']
button[href*='link2']
button[href*='link3']
```

Comment: I found a chrome extension that helps me find the xpath to a button as if in this case. Your explications made a lot more sense and I actually tried it and it worked. I managed to complete the test clicking on the correct button. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No automatic tool will give you a correct locator in most cases, you have to learn how to create locators by yourself

Comment: Okay, understood. I will try as a best practice then to locate the elements based on what you gave me here today. Thank you for your input!